# What's the right approach to "teach" a chatbot about a big specific data set: training it or feeding it the input once?

Tags: generative-model, chat-bots, large-language-models

I would like to build a chatbot that I can talk to about any specific data set I provide and I have a theoretical question.

Let's say, I want to discuss French cuisine. This could involve providing the model with information like culinary history, biographies of French chefs, French cookbooks, etc.

Now, **the question**: Assuming I have all this huge data set, what would be the correct, more efficient approach?

1. Do I use the data set to *train* the model, so that later I can talk to it?, or
2. Do I simply *feed all this text-based information* to the model as a system message and instruct the model to analyze the text before it gives any answers?

So, essentially, training or providing large, one-time input?